# get_map in Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, ggmap

The following code

```
map<-get_map(location=params$chosenState, zoom=6,maptype='hybrid',source="google")
data<-sightings[sightings$State==params$chosenState, ]
ggmap(map, base_layer=ggplot(aes(x=lng,y=lat),data=data)) +geom_point(color="red",alpha=0.3)
```

works just fine at the console, provided I have set up a dataframe called params and read my data into a dataframe called sightings.  It produces this plot when params$chosenState is "OH".

[image]

However, when I move everything into a Markdown document

````
---
title: "UFOs"
output: html_document
params:
  chosenState: "OH"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
sightings<- read.csv("UFOs_coord.csv",header=TRUE)
UFOPlot<-function(){
  map<-get_map(location=params$chosenState, zoom = 6,maptype='hybrid',source="google")
  data<-sightings[sightings$State==params$chosenState, ]
  ggmap(map, base_layer=ggplot(aes(x=lng,y=lat),data=data))
}
```

## UFO Sightings

Below is the locations of UFO sightings in  ``r params$chosenState``
```{r}
UFOPlot()
```
````

and go to knit it, I get this error message

> Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL =
>   integer(0))) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed Calls:
>    ... lapply -> FUN ->  -> f ->  -> f

I'm wondering if there isn't something basic about using ggmap in Markdown that I'm missing?  This is the first time I've ever tried to do it.

Here is the start of the dataframe data

```
     Date...Time Country          City State    Shape      lat       lng
9   12/19/16 18:30     USA Huber Heights    OH Cylinder 39.85902 -84.11136
21  12/18/16 19:00     USA     Lancaster    OH    Light 39.71368 -82.59933
321 11/18/16 23:30     USA      Columbus    OH Cylinder 39.96226 -83.00071
326 11/18/16 19:15     USA   Stone Creek    OH Triangle 40.39729 -81.56206
327 11/18/16 18:30     USA    Carrollton    OH   Circle 40.57284 -81.08565
336 11/17/16 21:30     USA        Athens    OH    Light 39.32924 -82.10126
```

UPDATE:

Maybe I had something wrong with my logical subscripting? dplyr and the ggmap call suggested by Dhiraj seemed to do the trick.  This document knits just fine

````
---
title: "UFOs"
output: html_document
params:
  chosenState: "OH"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning=FALSE)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
sightings<- read.csv("UFOs_coord.csv",header=TRUE)
UFOPlot<-function(){
  map<-get_map(location=params$chosenState, zoom = 6,maptype='hybrid',source="google")
  data <- sightings %>% select(-Summary, -Shape) %>% filter(State==params$chosenState)
  ggmap(map) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=lng,y=lat), color="red", alpha=0.3)

}
```
## UFO Sightings

Below is the locations of UFO sightings in  ``r params$chosenState``
```{r}
UFOPlot()
```
````

Comment: I am assuming `params$chosenState` is Ohio. Can you please add some lat long values from `sightings` for Ohio so that this is reproducible?

Comment: right, I was setting it up to be a markdown document with parameters so that you could choose a state.  I will edit the OP to include the complete Markdown document and the head of the data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following in a code chunk in a rmarkdown file and it seems to be working fine:

```
library(ggmap)
lat <- 39.86+rnorm(10,0.5)
lng <- -82.59 + rnorm(10, 0.5)
sightings <- data.frame(cbind(lng,lat))

map<-get_map(location='Ohio', zoom = 6,maptype='hybrid',source="google")
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data=sightings, aes(x=lng,y=lat))
```